# ClickOnce para DotNetCore

Tags: .net-core, console-application, clickonce

Bom dia.
Temos um projeto Console Application em DotnetCore 3.0.
Precisamos gerar um instalador nos moldes do ClickOnce do DotnetFramework. Para além de gerar o instalador, ele seja atualizado automaticamente.
Mas ai está alguns problemas:
Só estamos podendo usar o VisualCode e não temos acesso para instalação de ferramentas de terceiros. No máximo componentes e nugets do visual code.

Li muito sobre o MSIX, mas todos os tutoriais pedem o Visual Studio.

Existe algum outro modo?

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: `ClickOnce` é bom pelo Visual Studio Completo (qualquer versão) que no caso é a guia Publish, outras ferramentas acho que não tem, bom pelo menos nunca vi, porque é muito fácil pelo Visual Studio. A sua pergunta também é fora do escopo do site, não é de programação

Comment: A sua pergunta parece estar [fora do nosso escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Mas felizmente a rede [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) conta com o site [Super User](https://superuser.com/) que é um Q&A voltado para usuários de Software e Hardware em geral. Se preferir você pode encaminhar sua pergunta a essa comunidade, lembrando que é um comunidade independente da nossa que portanto possui suas próprias regras é gerida em língua inglesa.

Comment: Obrigado e desculpe. Achei que a pergunta fizesse sentido, pois envolve a linguagem de programação dotnet core, e a publicação de uma aplicação.